# Concat While looping

Tags: c#, xml, string, list, xpath

I have a method which parses XML for the start and end date through the xpath.

```
List<string> GetWorkNodeDate = new List<string>();
List<string> GetWorkNodeEstablisment = new List<string>();

XmlNodeList WorkNodeListDate = XmlResponceDoc.SelectNodes("/response/employees/employee/starttime | /response/employees/employee/endtime");

if (WorkNodeListDate != null)
{
    foreach (XmlNode StartDate in WorkNodeListDate)
    {
        string GetStartDate = StartDate.InnerText;
        GetWorkNodeDate.Add(GetStartDate);
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that every time it has done the loop twice from many which are stored in the xml to gather the start and end date I want to concat them two values then store them in to the List. I was just wondering what is the best way to achieve this? Thanks for any help which you can provide.

Comment: _"every time it has done the loop twice "_ why and where?

Comment: Can you show some sample XML-data so we can try out?

Comment: The issue at the moment the list is storing the start and end date one after one after the other and I am not sure how to concat them while the process is going on or after

Comment: How about iterating each employee by using the XPath `/response/employees/employee` and the simply accessing the `starttime` and `endtime` elements?

Comment: @Martin Liversage That has work perfectly thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a for-loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < WorkNodeListDate.Count; i = i + 2)
{
    string startAndStoptime = WorkNodeListDate[i].InnerText + "..." + WorkNodeListDate[i + 1];
}
```

You can access the start and stoptimes and put them together. You'd have to store them somewhere yourself, obviously.

The iterator gets upped with 2 each time, because then you will access another starttime. Also note that it checks if `i-1` is smaller than the count. This because i+1 is not another starttime, but a stoptime. So the upping of i has to stop when the list "runs out" of starttimes.

Result would be: `starttime...stoptime`